# How to connect SharePoint Online with Dynamics CRM using Web Part?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, dynamics-crm

How connect Dynamics CRM Online with SharePoint Online using Web Part - Microsoft Dynamics CRM List Component?

I Try to use in SharePoint a web part Microsoft Dynamics CRM List Component to connect and import data from Dynamics CRM Online.
I mean that I want to view list of account from Dynamics CRM in SharePoint Online like a list o customers. 
Is there any possibility to make this? And how do that using SharePoint Designer 2010 or Visual Studio or only web interface?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also looking for something similar. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- Option 1: From SharePoint Point of View:
  You can use the webservices to import data from CRM Online. Any 'end
  user' solutions all require access to the CRM Database, which is not
  available in the Online version. You have to synchronise from
  SharePoint to make sure that accounts are in sync.
- Option 2: From Dynamics CRM PoV:
  Write a plugin that pushes the needed information to the SharePoint list, again, via webparts. Make sure you handle create, update and delete and make sure that users cannot edit the list via SharePoint.

I think the second option is the most solid.